# Dependency injection - resolve complex interface implementation

Tags: c#, .net-core

**Overview**

In my application (*.net core 1.1*), I have a following classes and interfaces:

```
class RequestingUserData
interface IQuery<TResult>
interface IQueryWithUser<TResult> : IQuery<TResult>
class UserSearchQuery : IQueryWithUser<RequestingUserData>

interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery, TResult> where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
interface IUserSearchQueryHandler<T> : IQueryHandler<T, RequestingUserData> where T : IQueryWithUser<RequestingUserData> 
class UserSearchQueryHandler : IUserSearchQueryHandler<UserSearchQuery>
```

As a dependency injection I'm using `IServiceCollection` inside [`ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup#the-configureservices-method) method.

Classes are resolved in runtime using `IServiceProvider` interface created from `IServiceCollection`:

```
//Somewhere in ConfigureServices
services.AddScoped<IServiceCollection>(x => services);

//SomeClass in which I want to resolve 
SomeClass(IServiceCollection services){// SomeClass's constructor
  _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
//Later in SomeClass
var resolved = _serviceProvider.GetService<IQueryHandler<IQueryWithUser<RequestingUserData>, RequestingUserData>>(); // this becomes null
```

**What I want to achieve**

I want to get `UserSearchQueryHandler` class instance in last line in the snippet above.

I believe it's not going to work because there is no class explicitly implementing `IQueryHandler<IQueryWithUser<RequestingUserData>, RequestingUserData>`.
However, there is a class that implements `IQueryWithUser<RequestingUserData>` so it should be possible to do this somehow.

**What I tried**

This is how I add my class to services:

```
services.AddScoped<IQueryHandler<UserSearchQuery, RequestingUserData>, UserSearchQueryHandler>();
```

I also tried to do this that way:

```
 services.AddScoped<IQueryHandler<IQueryWithUser<RequestingUserData>, RequestingUserData>, UserSearchQueryHandler>();
```

but it gives a compilation error (which is reasonable).

**Question**

Is it possible to do what I'm thinking of ? If no, can you see how could I rearrange my interfaces to make it possible?

Comment: To the one that `-1` my question, could you give some information how can I improve it?

Comment: Is this due to contravariance of `IQueryHandler<in TQuery, TResult>`?

Comment: Using a Service Resolver is an anti-pattern. You should add the actual interfaces you want to your constructor and allow the built-in DI of dotnet core to do the resolving.

Comment: @CalC unfortunately not.
@ Boggin while in general I agree, I need it to resolve handlers in dispatcher in my CQRS implementation